# Do I need to read Ian Cameron Esslemont's novels?

Tags: suggested-order, malazan

I am currently up to book 6 in the Malazan Book of the Fallen.

Having solely read Steven Erikson's line, am I missing out on vital information.

I know that the two lines are somewhat separate but cannot find if I need to read both to fully appreciate the story.

For example are there gaps in the Erikson series that are explained by the works of Esslemont?

Comment: i read the entire erikson story line before reading the esslemont novels, and felt i didnt miss anything.  you may glean some extra information about certain events but nothing that directly impacts the story.

Comment: @Himarm did you feel you missed out on anything by doing it this way?

Comment: na, the esslemont novels arnt as good anyway imo.

Comment: You dont need to read them while you are reading Eriksons books. But I would recommend reading them afterwards because they are quite ok. Same world, some of the same characters etc. Just dont expect the same quality as Erikson.